# Align 2 different elements differently in a flex box

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

```
<figure class="flex justify-center items-center">
   <img src="something.png">
   <a href="#"><img src="somethingelse.png"></a>
</figure>
```

I have used Tailwindcss for `<figure>`, the css rules are what they sound like.

Now the above centers both `<img>` and `<a>` but what I want is to center `<img>` but bottom-right the `<a>` along with the containing `<img>`

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS justify-self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self) and [CSS align-self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) on your `<a>` tag to achieve what you want. Try playing with the examples in the links I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a div! I replaced your classes with bootstrap 4 classes, but you should be able to sort it out!

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<figure class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-end">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300">
   <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/80"></a>
  </div>
</figure>
```